# How to save the value of a radio button?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I save the value of a radio button from function.php?

Here's my full code in function.php. Text filled is working but I don't know how the radio will work.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'ccheck_set');

function ccheck_set() 
{
  add_menu_page('ccheck', 'Sidebar', 'edit_posts', 'ccheck', 'ccheck', 'dashicons-media-spreadsheet');
}

function ccheck()
{
  if($_POST['radio_clr'])
  {
    if (!empty(get_option('radio_clr', $_POST['radio_clr'])))
    {
      update_option('radio_clr', $_POST['radio_clr']);
    }
    else
    {
      add_option('radio_clr', $_POST['radio_clr']);
    }
  }
  echo '<form  method="POST"><table>
        <tr><td ><input type="radio" name="radio_clr" value="0"  >red
<input type="radio" name="radio_clr"  value="1" >Black</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
    </table></form>';
  }
```

Comment: you put jquery as a tag, but I don't see any javascript/jquery code in your example? Are you simply asking how to fetch a value of a radio button with the use of jquery? If that's the case, you simply fetch it by name `$("input[name='radioName']:checked").val();` or by id `$("input#nameOfId:checked").val();`

Comment: yeah you are right but i want it by php

Comment: I think you are mixing 2 worlds. Javascript is where you handle your client-side things, i.e. such as getting and parsing values etc. The PHP can then interpret and make use of these values server-side. I.e. by `POST` or `GET` variables. I.e. you can have a form with method `POST` or `GET` and then retrieve the values like so `$radioVar = $_POST['nameOfRadioButton'];` or `$radioVar = $_GET['nameOfRadioButton'];` Like I said, you can do this via a form, but you can also use AJAX calls for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function instead for *radio buttons*.

```
function ccheck()
{
    if($_POST['radio_clr']!="")
    {
        if ( get_option( 'radio_clr' ) !== false )
        {
            update_option( 'radio_clr', $_POST['radio_clr'] );
        }
        else
        {
            add_option( 'radio_clr', $_POST['radio_clr'] );
        }
    }
    echo '<form method="POST"><table>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="radio_clr" value="0" ';
    if(get_option( 'radio_clr' )=="0") echo 'checked="checked"';
    echo '>Red
    <input type="radio" name="radio_clr" value="1" ';
    if(get_option( 'radio_clr' )=="1") echo 'checked="checked"';
    echo '>Black</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
    </table></form>';
}
```

Try this function instead for *image upload* but please note that this is **not a professional or secure way**. You need to use WordPress core functions.

```
function ccheck()
{
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $target_folder = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/options';

    if ($_FILES['option_file_upload']['name']!="")
    {
        $filename = time().$_FILES['option_file_upload']['name'];

        if(!(is_dir($target_folder)))
            mkdir($target_folder);

        copy($_FILES['option_file_upload']['tmp_name'], $target_folder."/".$filename);      

        if ( get_option( 'option_file_upload' ) !== false )
        {
            update_option( 'option_file_upload', $filename );
        }
        else
        {
            add_option( 'option_file_upload', $filename );
        }
    }
    echo '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><table>
    <tr><td><input type="file" name="option_file_upload" />';
    if(get_option( 'option_file_upload' )!="") echo ' <img src="'.site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/options/'.get_option( 'option_file_upload' ).'">';
    echo '</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
    </table></form>';
}
```

Try this function instead for *check boxes* which should be an array. Don't use '0' as checkbox value.

```
function ccheck()
{
    if($_POST['check_clr']!="")
    {
        if ( get_option( 'check_clr' ) !== false )
        {
            update_option( 'check_clr', $_POST['check_clr'] );
        }
        else
        {
            add_option( 'check_clr', $_POST['check_clr'] );
        }
    }

    $check_clr=get_option( 'check_clr' );

    echo '<form method="POST"><table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="check_clr[]" value="1" ';
    if(in_array('1', $check_clr )) echo 'checked="checked"';
    echo '>Red
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_clr[]" value="2" ';
    if(in_array('2', $check_clr )) echo 'checked="checked"';
    echo '>Black</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
    </table></form>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Outsource can you give me our email id for other one query.

Comment: i can place query here
my query is that like recently you did radio button query ..
confussion is that how we can do for image

Comment: my last question for checkbox ..please.

Comment: Added, please check. Note the array in the checkbox names.